# I'm making a blackjack game, and I'm wondering why doesn't my function numbertocard update the definition of playercard1

Tags: python, function, function-definition

I want to use a face card value instead of the number if the card is greater then 10 but the function doesn't update the variable.

The "card" used in the function does get updated to playercard1 when I call upon it with numbertocard(playercard1), right? And if so, what exactly is the issue?

```
import random
def numbertocard(card):
  if card == 11:
    card == "J"
  elif card == 12:
    card == "Q"
  elif card == 13:
    card = "K"
  elif card == 14:
    card = "A"
  else:
    card = card
    return card

def cardtonumber(cardvalue):
  if cardvalue == "J":
    cardvalue == 11
  elif cardvalue == "Q":
    cardvalue == 12
  elif cardvalue == "K":
    cardvalue = 13
  else:
    cardvalue = "A"
    return cardvalue
    



def startgame():
  playercard1 = random.randint(1,14)
  numbertocard(playercard1)
  print(f"Your first card is {playercard1}")


def menu():
  play_game = input("Would you like to start a round? y/n: \n")
  if play_game == "y":
    startgame()
  else:
    print("""Say "y" """ )
    menu()



menu()
```

Comment: `if card == 11: card == "J"` vs. `elif cardvalue == "K": cardvalue = 13`: Sometimes you use `=`, sometimes you use `==`. They do different things. Can you see which one you should use in each case?

Comment: For this kind of small programs, adding `print`s for values and types can help you to understand what's not working. For example, you could add `print(card)` after before and after each assignation to see what's happening. See [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some other tips.

Comment: Also, check the indentation in the `return` statement.

Comment: Ohh my bad, I should use == to see if the card generated is that number, and == to make card become the new letter, right? i.e if card == 11, card = "J"

Comment: And what do you expect `card = card` to do?

Comment: Yes, `card == 11, card = "J"` should do it. But also you want to have always a return, not only when the card is not a face. In fact, you could just do `return "J"` or even use a dictionary to store the conversions and do something like `return card_values[card]` (but you need to have a way of dealing with no-faces).

Comment: Its supposed to do nothing so if the card is a 10 or lower it will keep its name, because only the face cards have a name that is different to the number they represent

Comment: But then some cards are integers and some are strings... Later you'll want to make functions that take cards as input and do something with them, so it will help to represent them in a coherent way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by creating a new variable that stores the returning value of that function:

```
def startgame():
  playercard1 = random.randint(1,14)
  cardValue = numbertocard(playercard1)
  print(f"Your first card is {cardValue}")
```

or directly:

```
def startgame():
  playercard1 = random.randint(1,14)
  print(f"Your first card is {numbertocard(playercard1)}")
```

Check this out for further information of what's happening: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-python-call-by-reference-or-call-by-value